# height is not working properly but width is

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function etchsketch(numOfSquares) {

  for (let j = 0; j < numOfSquares; j++) {
    let currentrow = document.createElement('p')
    document.getElementById('pixels').append(currentrow)

    for (let y = 0; y < numOfSquares; y++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div')
      currentrow.append(div)
      div.classList.add('unhover')
    }
  }

  let color = "black"
  let oldColor

  document.getElementById('colors').addEventListener('click', e => {
    oldColor = color
    if (e.target.innerText === 'red')
      color = "red"
    if (e.target.innerText === 'green')
      color = "green"
    if (e.target.innerText === 'blue')
      color = "blue"
    if (e.target.innerText === 'black')
      color = 'black'
    if (e.target.innerText === 'ereaser')
      color = 'white'
  })

  for (let i = 0; i < (numOfSquares * numOfSquares); i++) {
    console.log("remove " + oldColor)
    document.getElementsByClassName('unhover')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('unhover')[i].classList.remove(oldColor);
    })
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < (numOfSquares * numOfSquares); i++) {
    console.log("add " + color)
    document.getElementsByClassName('unhover')[i].addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('unhover')[i].classList.add(color);
    })
  }

}

let total = prompt("What size do you want the Square? (<100)")

while (total > 100) {
  total = prompt("MUST BE LESS THAN 100")
}

etchsketch(total)
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533628635777-112b2239b1c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

#pixels {
  height: 960px;
  width: 960px;
}

div {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 10;
  border: .12em solid black;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  margin: .12em;
  gap: .12em
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

.black,
.blue,
.red,
.green,
.white {
  transition: .65s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main id="colors">
    <button>red</button>
    <button>green</button>
    <button>blue</button>
    <button>black</button>
    <button>ereaser</button>
  </main>
  <main id="pixels"></main>
</body>
```

The program is supposed to be an etch-a-sketch. Basically, you can change the color on a screen from white to black/red/blue/green or back to white.
The height doesn't stop at 960px. The width is also set to 960px but stops at 960px, but the height keeps going. Is there anyway to make it so the height does stop at 960px? I can't seem to find a solution online.

Comment: for you `div` css, instead of `height:1em;` do `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;`

Comment: I can't see the problem, the height doens't 'keep going' for me. Incidentally what do you want to happen if the user chooses an n such that n*1em > viewport width?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't see a difference between setting height 1em and using aspect-ratio - except using aspect ratio won't work on IE or e.g. IOS systems which haven't been updated in the last few months.

Comment: @AHaworth nobody cares about IE ... but I agree .. .but on the OP's code it DOES make a difference